# Board Game Design in Cocos2d

Tags: game-design, cocos2d-iphone

I am going to start a chess like board game. And for that I have reviewed a number of things available.

One is http://www.mapeditor.org/, using which you can create a grid base games.

Another option is geekgameboard for iphone available at http://mooseyard.lighthouseapp.com/projects/23201-geekgameboard

Now I want your expert opinion on what would be better to make a game in cocos2d, using the first option or the second option? Both looks promising to me and give good control over board design.

PS: Sorry for duplicates, I found about the https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ lately after posting it on stackexchange. So I am just posting it here again as I feel this is a more relevant board.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use a tile-editor for a game like chess. The board is really simple and you can easily draw it without the help of a tile-editor. These maps make much more sense if you have a large world/board with lots of different tiles.

I don't know the GeekGameBoard you linked to, but it looks like it's a framework for card and board-games, so this seems much more suited for your task. It seems like this framework provides several UI elements, so you'll probably either choose GeekGameBoard *or* Cocos2d. Mixing the two would most likely force you to rewrite/refactor a lot of the GeekGameBoard code (which might be more work than starting your game-code from scratch).

Comment: yes you were right,  i have started it in geekgameboard becuase it give complete framework for board and let you concentrate on game logic.